# changing font size does not work in content editor webpart - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, content, editor

I have SharePoint 2010 site with **custom master page** and custom css. The link to css file is referenced in master page. In the custom css, font size for hyperlinks is specified as 10px. Users add **content editor webpart** to pages and format them as required.

But when I try to increase the font size from the drop down  Content Editor tool bar in ribbon (under Format Text Category) it does not change the font size. It still picks the one from css file. It takes the size mentioned in custom css file and not the one user is trying to specify. Now you can specify font-size parameter `style="font-size: 14px"` for the hyperlink by clicking on **Edit HTML Source**, but users are not happy with this approach and it becomes very difficult if there are lots of html contents.

Is there any other solution to this issue?

[image]

Comment: you can add script editor on page and override that particular css part.

Comment: Your image is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Check if  the css class does not seal the property via **!important** keyword. and if you can post the css class to see how the property is set.

Comment: When dealing with ``!important`` do read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805040/relationship-between-important-and-css-specificity